# Docking with ToolStrip and Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

In Form have ToolStrip and Panel. ToolStrip's Dock value is set to Top, Panel's to Fill. But ToolStrip intervens into Panel and hide first line of Panel. How to set, that toolstrip doesn't hide panel?

I don't want to use MenuStrip, which don't hide anything, but for some reasons i don't want to use it.
Thanks for reply

Comment: You could (in addition to `im_a_noob`'s perfectly correct answer also consider using a `ToolStripContainer`, adding the `ToolStrip` to the top bar and the `Panel` to the client area.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have to change the order of the 2 control in *Document Outline*.

In order to do that go to :

> View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline

or use the shortcut keys

> ctrl + w, u

then reorder the two controls. If I'm right you should put your *Panel* first and your *ToolStrip* after.

Comment: Alternatively you can also use the respective layout buttons in Visual Studio's designer toolbars.

Comment: A Faster way is to just right click the Panel and choose "Bring to front"

Comment: Had the same issue. Indeed the panel should come BEFORE the ToolStrip. This is a little counter-intuitive because from a logical perspective the ToolStrip is laid out first, and only then can the panel be resized to fill ther remaining space. Also, by default VS seems to place the ToolStrip first even when it is added to the form after the panel - as it was in my case. So thnx for the solution and the equally helpful comments above.